# cant able to find the right xpath for active element

Tags: selenium, xpath-2.0

i am not able to find the active xpath (the fare bundle which are displayed only on flight selection page ) for the fare bundle in flight selection page .
i have tried all , when i have been trying i am getting the total counts of webelement (fare bundle) which is included both active and inactive . this is causing me problem to select the active xpath .when i am running the loop , the moment the loop point out to inactive (the webelement which is not pointing any farebundle in UI but shown in developer tool) , it is getting failed as that webelemet is not displayed on UI . need your help/

```
xpath : 

<div class="colRadio">::before
<input type="radio" name="flightItineraryGroupId[0]_01" value="12" id="flightSelectGr_0_12" onclick="selectFareFamily(0, 1, 'AN'); fareFamiliesFlightSelection.selectFlight(this); reloadItinerarySummaryInfo(this, false)" class="" aria-labelledby="flightSelectGr_0_12Label  idFFTitleAN idFlightNumber2">
```

Note : 
    here only below html are constane and all rest are change based on

selected fare bundle

```
 <div class="colRadio">::before
```

i have tried 
`//div[@class="colRadio"] a`nd it is showing all webelement including inactive which is not displayed on UI .

```
 For (i=1;i<=count,i++)driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type=\"radio\"])["+i+"]")).click();
```

Expected : i want xpath which is only pointing web element present in Ui 
Actual: when i am running loop the loop is getting failed when it click on the web element which is not displayed in UI which is inactibe

```
 For (i=1;i<=count,i++)driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@type=\"radio\"])["+i+"]")).click();
```

Note: i want only active xpath count

Answer (score 1):

1. Get all radio buttons into a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) of [WebElements](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html) like:

   ```
   List<WebElement> allRadioButtons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='radio']"));
   ```

   hint: you can use single quote marks `'` in your [XPath queries](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) for better readability as you won't have to escape double quotation marks  `"` with a backslash `\`
2. [Filter out](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) only those which are currently visible:

   ```
   List<WebElement> visibleRadioButtons = allRadioButtons
           .stream()
           .filter(WebElement::isDisplayed)
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```
3. That's it, now `visibleRadioButtons` list will contain only those buttons which are currently displayed and can be interacted with.

   [image]